# I have difficulty understanding word pronominal

Tags: meaning

I can not understand what pronominal mean?

dictionaries say that it is "**of, relating to, or constituting a pronoun"**

I don't get  it what it means?

Comment: Do you know what a pronoun is? If something is pronominal, it is 'about pronouns'

Comment: The words "I" and "it" in your question are pronominal, because they are pronouns.